# Projection of moving point onto static curve and respective velocities / Frenet Coordinates

Tags: differential-geometry, curves, frenet-frame

Consider a curve in 2D $\vec{p}(s)$ parameterized by arclength $s$ and the usual local coordinate system on the curve (Frenet Frame with unit vectors $\vec{n}(s)\perp\vec{t}(s)$, no torsion, curvature non-zero). Further, consider a point $\vec{r}(t)$ and it's projection onto the curve $\vec{p}(s)$ at $\vec{r}_0=\vec{p}(s_0)$ as below:

[image]

I'm interested in the time derivative of the distance of $\vec{r}(t)$ from $\vec{p}(s)$ with respect to time, i.e. the derivative of $\delta(t) = \vec{n}^T(\vec{r}-\vec{r}_0)$ and here is what I've come up with:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\frac{d}{dt}\delta = & \frac{d}{dt}\vec{n}^T(\vec{r}-\vec{r}_0)\\
= & \left(\frac{ds}{dt}\frac{d}{ds}\vec{n}^T\right)(\vec{r}-\vec{r}_0) + \vec{n}^T(\frac{d}{dt}\vec{r}-\frac{ds}{dt}\frac{d}{ds}\vec{r}_0)\\
= & \underbrace{\frac{ds}{dt}\kappa\vec{t}(\vec{r}-\vec{r}_0)}_{\equiv 0,~\vec{t}\perp (\vec{r}-\vec{r}_0)} + \vec{n}^T\frac{d}{dt}\vec{r} - \frac{ds}{dt}\underbrace{\vec{n}^T\frac{d}{ds}\vec{r}_0}_{\equiv 0, \frac{d}{ds}\vec{r}_0\propto \vec{t}, \vec{t}\perp\vec{n}}\\
= & \vec{n}^T\frac{d}{dt}\vec{r}
\end{aligned}
$$

where I've used Frenet Sorret, i.e. $d/ds\vec{n}=\kappa\vec{t}$ and that $d/ds\vec{r}_0$ must always be proportional to $\vec{t}$ by construction of the projection.

If the above is correct, then the velocity of change of distance to the curve is only the projection of the object's velocity onto the curve's normal. That seems totally unintuitive to me as I would expect the curvature of $\vec{p}(s)$ to enter here as well.

Where am I wrong and what is the correct formula? Thanks for any help or reference suggestions.

Comment: Doesn't $s_0$ depend on $t$?  How do you determine $s_0$ for a given $t$?

Comment: We'll I define $\vec{r}_0(t) = \vec{p}(s_0(t))$, i.e. $\vec{r}_0$ is the projection point that moves with time as $\vec{r}(t)$ moves in time. In the second line above, you could replace $\frac{ds}{dt}\frac{d}{ds}$ with $\frac{ds_0}{dt}\frac{d}{ds_0}$. But that shouldn't change anything, should it?

Comment: Be aware that $s_0(t)$ may not be unique: take a circle $p$ and its center $r$.  Or such a $s_0(t)$ may not even exist.

Comment: Sure, but that is a special case. What I'm trying to figure out is: is my math or my intuition wrong?

Comment: How do you calculate $s_0(t)$?  That's for beyond being trivial.  The function may not be continuous or differentiable.

Comment: Not sure I understand your diagram and notation; is the following equivalent? Given the path $p$, we consider the family of normal lines through points of $p$, and assume we're in a region where these lines, together with distance from $p$, define plane coordinates. Then, given the motion of $r$, we want to calculate the rate of change of distance from $r$ to $p$? If so, your calculation looks right, and the intuition appears to be that the curvature of $p$ affects which normal line $r(t)$ is on, but not the distance from $r(t)$ to $p$.

Comment: Yes, your understanding is correct and I think I found the lapse in my intuition. The fact that $\dot\delta$ equals the component of $\dot{\vec{r}}$ in the direction of the normal on the curve and is unaffected by the curvature comes from the fact that $\vec{r}_0$ is always at the _minimum_ distance of $\vec{p}(s)$ and $\vec{r}$, and there, indeed, the contribution of the curvature vanishes. One can see this considering $\vec{p}(s)$ as a circle with radius $R$, i.e. you consider $\vec{r}$ in polar coordinates.